# Nested promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, breeze, q

**nested promises**

I am using breeze with angular, my language is Typescript

```
.then((account: IAccount) => {
     for (let i = account.workspaces.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         for (let j = account.workspaces[i].apps.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
             appDataService.getApp(account.workspaces[i].apps[j].id)
                         **.then((app) => {
                             **apps.push(app);**
                         });**
             account.workspaces[i].apps.splice(j, 1);
         }
     }
     return account;
})
.then((account) => {
    for (let i = apps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        appDataService.deleteApp(apps[i]);
    }
    ..... // more awesome code here
    return account;
 })
```

I have a nested promise

```
appDataService.getApp(account.workspaces[i].apps[j].id)
              .then((app) => {
                  apps.push(app); 
              });
```

but when I get in the next `.then` the length of the array **apps** is 0.

I have checked and double checked. it is not a problem with the `getApp` function. :)

Can you please explain me how to wait for that nested promise?

Comment: can you add a plunker for it

Comment: Sorry i don't think it's an option for me.

Comment: Where you defined `apps` and are you sure `getApp` returns anything?

Comment: `getApp()` is asynchronous. You will need to return a promise that doesn't resolve until all of the `getApp()` calls have completed.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all - try using this

Comment: Thank you very much Charlietfl. you've open new horizons for me :)  to bad i can not mark your comment as the answer